# No GUI after ubuntu 15.04 upgrade

Tags: boot, command-line, upgrade, 15.04

I tried updating to 15.04. I can't get to the GUI. At boot I get a txt message "starting version 2.19 and then a terminal log in comes up. My login works but none of the terminal solutions I have found on Ask Ubuntu work. I tried creating a ubuntu USB drive and even after resetting the computer to boot from the USB drive first. the computer just ends up with the version 2.19. I don't know a lot of ubuntu commands. The only reason I am familiar with the commands is that I used a command line in the DOS days. Please help

Comment: I was experiencing the same problem as you, but on netrunner 17. Manually upgrading my desktop environment solved it for me. `sudo apt-get install <your_DE>`

Answer (score 0):

Try the `startx` command to open the GUI after having logged in.